# Python 3.6 NameError: name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.6, nameerror

I have the following code to create a blockchain.

```
class Blockchain(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.chain= []
        self.current_transactions = []

        # Create the genesis block
        self.new_block(previous_hash=1, proof=100)

        def proof_of_work(slef, last_proof):
            """
            Simple proof of Work Algorithm:
            - Find a number p' such that hash(pp') contains leading 4 zeros, where p isthe previous p'
            - p is the previous proof, and p'is the new proof

            :param last_proof: <int>
            :return: <int>
            """

        proof = 0
        while self.valid_proof(last_proof, proof) is False:
            proof += 1

        return proof

    # Insantiate the Blockchain
    blockchain = Blockchain()
```

In this code, when I attempt to use Flask to run that code, it returns the following error:

`"NameError: name 'Blockchain' is not defined"`

Comment: You can't instantiate a class inside of itself. outdent `blockchain = Blockchain()`

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: how I'm going to fix it? Deleting that part?

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace matters in python.  Your last line

```
blockchain = Blockchain()
```

needs the whitespace removed to match the whitespace of the your `class` definition, and you need to indent your `def __init__(self):`

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @xAssasinSoulx whitespace is the number of spaces or tabs between some characters and the beginning of a newline.  In python you can't just arbitrarily use whitespace however you want, it needs to line up within the scope it's being used.  If this doesn't make sense to you I'd recommend reading some more python tutorials

Comment: oooo, yeah yeah yeah, I get it